# How to initialise a variable in secondary constructor and call super in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
class Car: FourWheeler {
   lateinit var engine: Engine  

   constructor(fuel: Fuel) {
      engine = Engine(fuel)
      super(engine)
   }
}
```

This is throwing error. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the constructor into two constructors like this:

```
class Car: FourWheeler {
    var engine: Engine

    private constructor(engine: Engine) : super(engine) {
        this.engine = engine
    }

    constructor(fuel: Fuel) : this(Engine(fuel))
}
```

Or even make the private constructor a primary one:

```
class Car private constructor(var engine: Engine): FourWheeler(engine) {
    constructor(fuel: Fuel) : this(Engine(fuel))
}
```

You don't need `lateinit` as `engine` is initialized in the constructor.

Also, as `FourWheeler` accepts `engine` in its constructor, you can expose it as a `protected` property, so it will be available for all its subtypes. Depending on your specific case it could make sense or not.